# IOS Parse is my nested query a good solution for comparing an object with a pointer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

Currently, I am querying the database twice to achieve a list of all users nearby who are not already being followed by the current user. Here is my nested query:

```
// List of all users being followed by the current user
PFQuery *followingActivitiesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kFTActivityClassKey];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kFTActivityTypeKey equalTo:kFTActivityTypeFollow];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kFTActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[followingActivitiesQuery setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];
[followingActivitiesQuery includeKey:kFTActivityToUserKey];
[followingActivitiesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        NSMutableArray *followedUserIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // Obtain an array of object ids for all users being followed
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            PFUser *followedUser = [object objectForKey:kFTActivityToUserKey];
            [followedUserIds addObject:followedUser.objectId];
        }

        PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:kFTUserLocationKey];

        // List of all users within 50 miles that are not already being followed
        PFQuery *followUsersByLocationQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kFTUserClassKey];
        [followUsersByLocationQuery whereKey:kFTUserObjectIdKey notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
        [followUsersByLocationQuery whereKey:kFTUserLocationKey nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinMiles:50];
        [followUsersByLocationQuery whereKeyExists:kFTUserLocationKey];
        [followUsersByLocationQuery whereKey:kFTUserObjectIdKey notContainedIn:followedUserIds];
        [followUsersByLocationQuery setLimit:100];
        [followUsersByLocationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                self.objects = objects;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

My question is, is this a viable solution? I feel guilty about having to query the server twice in order to achieve this, but I was not able to do it all in one query. I could not compare a parse pointer from the ActivityClass to the Users class, since the Users class is the class being pointed to, and because of this I couldn't think of a way to do it all in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck - this can be done in a single query using the `whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery:` method of `PFQuery`.

Parse will treat this as a single, compound query against the database. Totally guilt-free :)

Try this instead:

```
// List of all users being followed by the current user
PFQuery *followingActivitiesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kFTActivityClassKey];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kFTActivityTypeKey equalTo:kFTActivityTypeFollow];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kFTActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[followingActivitiesQuery setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly];
[followingActivitiesQuery includeKey:kFTActivityToUserKey];

PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:kFTUserLocationKey];

// List of all users within 50 miles that are not already being followed
PFQuery *followUsersByLocationQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kFTUserClassKey];
[followUsersByLocationQuery whereKey:kFTUserObjectIdKey notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
[followUsersByLocationQuery whereKey:kFTUserLocationKey nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinMiles:50];
[followUsersByLocationQuery whereKeyExists:kFTUserLocationKey];
//The next line is your new compound query
[followUsersByLocationQuery whereKey:kFTUserObjectIdKey doesNotMatchKey:@"objectId" inQuery:followingActivitiesQuery];
[followUsersByLocationQuery setLimit:100];
[followUsersByLocationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.objects = objects;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for attempting that. Unfortunately, this isn't going to work because `kFTActivityClassKey` contains a pointer to the `kFTUserClassKey` and using inQuery with these two will only compare the `objectId` of these two classes, as opposed to comparing the pointers objectId for the pointer from `kFTActivityClassKey` to `kFTUserClassKey`. It's not going to use the objectIds of the class being pointed to. But thank you that was worth a shot!

Comment: Well, drat. :) Good luck all the same!